# JSON based coloring of nodes in sankey.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In reference to D3 Sankey (https://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/), I wished to inquire about the way to color the nodes using some categorical variable in JSON file.

Link to the JSON file being used in the actual code:
https://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/energy.json

My question therefore is that if I provide some info pertaining to the category of "name":

```
{"name":"Solar PV", "category":"A"},
{"name":"Solar Thermal","category":"A"},
{"name":"Solar","category":"B"},
{"name":"Tidal","category":"C"},
{"name":"UK land based bioenergy","category":"A"},
{"name":"Wave","category":"A"},
{"name":"Wind","category":"B"}
```

Then what changes should be made to the source code to color the nodes according to the category.
P.S: Not an expert in D3/JS, please pardon my limited skills if this question appears too naive.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the edit and your previous comment Gerardo.
I was actually looking for coloring nodes using a categorical variable in JSON (multiple nodes might get same color), so that legend corresponding to Node category would make the Sankey more informative.

Getting cues from your comment, I am trying approaching the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the linked example you'll see this block of code:

```
node.append("rect")
  .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy; })
  .attr("width", sankey.nodeWidth())
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, "")); })
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2); })
  .append("title")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });
```

Replace the `.style("fill"` line with:

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return d.color = color(d.category); })
```

Comment: Thanks Mark...did the same yesterday.

Comment: Hi,
I was curious if one can arrange the Sankey nodes in concentric circles (as it inherently organizes the nodes in a hierarchical sort of format).

Comment: @NaSu, nothing built into the sankey plugin will do that for you.  From a comment in the source code: `// Nodes are assigned the maximum breadth of incoming neighbors plus one;  // nodes with no incoming links are assigned breadth zero, while // nodes with no outgoing links are assigned the maximum breadth.`  Perhaps you want something similar to the [radial tree](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550).

Answer (score 3):

In Bostock's code, this is the line that colours the rectangles:

```
.style("fill", function(d) { 
    return d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, "")); 
})
```

So, just change that to:

```
.style("fill", function(d) { 
    return d.color = color(d.category); 
})
```

Comment: Thanks Gerardo...did the same